# Python: Understanding Threading and Exiting Threads

Tags: python, multithreading

This is my first time working with threading. I think I understand the basics, but I'm not sure how exiting threads work.

Consider the code:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.name = name
    self.counter = counter
    self.stoprequest=threading.Event()
  def run(self):
    while not self.stoprequest.isSet():
      print("Starting " + self.name)
      print_time(self.name,self.counter)
      print("Exiting " + self.name)

  def join(self, timeout=None):
    self.stoprequest.set()
    super(myThread,self).join(timeout)

def print_time(threadName, delay):
  time.sleep(delay)
  print("%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))


thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print("Exiting Main Thread")
```

From what I understand of threading, they should never end until `join()` is called, but the code is exiting after only 1 cycle within the while-loop per thread. The output:

```
Starting Thread-1
Starting Thread-2
Exiting Main Thread
Thread-1: Wed Mar 13 09:13:32 2019
Exiting Thread-1
Thread-2: Wed Mar 13 09:13:33 2019
Exiting Thread-2
```

Note: I did not write this code myself, I found code online and adjusted it to try and get a better understanding of threading.

So my questions:

1. In the above code, why are the threads only executing one cycle of the while loop when `join()` is never being called? I would expect the threads to be never ending.
2. How would I make a threading program run until the user decides to exit it? My main goal is to have a script scan and analyze files until the user tells it to quit.

Thanks!

Comment: The output line `Exiting Main Thread` looks suspicious to me. Where is this `Main Thread` started in the first place?

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed a line when I pasted it over. It has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

The original answer is wrong, as it misses an important point that @ranjith suggested in comment section.

If you remove the `join` function in `myThread` definition, you will find that the program will not exit, as @ranjith mentioned. The reason is because, when the main thread exists, it automatically calls `join` on all its non-daemon threads, as shown here in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/threading.py#L1098). If you never implement `join` for your `myThread` class, calling `join` will return immediately without killing the child threads.

In your case, `join` is correctly implemented, which sets the `self.stoprequest` event to true, signaling the two child threads to stop. Therefore, when the main thread exits, the two children also exit.

Finally, one note on the differences between implementing `join` correctly vs not implementing `join` but set `daemon` to true, although they both behave similarly (child threads stop when main thread exists). If `daemon` is set to true, child threads will not be **wait til stop** when main thread exits (see Note in [this section](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/threading.py#L1098)), while implementing `join` does the opposite.

---

*original answer below*

This is because your python program exits, so that all children threads are killed implicitly. You need to keep your program running in order to see the two children threads keep printing things.

For example, replace the print statement at the end with this:

```
while True:
    print_time('Main', 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand that your while loop will be infinte, so then whats the point of having the condition of self.stoprequest? It was my understanding that `while not self.stoprequest.isSet():` acts as the infinite loop to keep the thread running?

Comment: Not sure that's true. If a thread is marked as daemon, then yes it exits with the main thread

Comment: @helloworld95 that is used to stop individual threads. For example, the main thread can invoke `thread1.join()` to stop thread1 while keeping thread2 running. If that is never called, all threads exit if the main thread exits.

Comment: @ranjith I think you are talking the opposite. If a thread is marked as daemon, the thread will not be killed automatically even the main thread exits. That’s kind of a special case but it’s good to mention.

Comment: No, I think it's the opposite :) and I did a bit of experiment myself to prove that and here's my observation.
If a thread is marked as a daemon, then basically you don't have to specifically wait for it to complete. It completes when main thread and other non-daemon threads exits.
In case of non-daemon, threads, even if you exit main, these threads continue to execute until they are complete/ exception

Comment: @ranjith Thanks for trying that out. I did a bit more research and figure out the reason. Answer is updated.

Comment: @helloworld95 In your case, you can let the main thread invoke the `join` function of a thread you want to stop, and that thread will be signaled to exit. If you want a user to actually hit enter to stop that thread, you need to use `input` (or something similar) in main thread to ask what the user want to do.

Answer (score 0):

**From what I understand of threading, they should never end until join() is called**

This is not true. It totally depends on how you implement the task to run in a thread. Either by overriding Thread class's run method or providing as your task (callable such as a function) as target (which will be called within Thread's run method ). Thread ends when the task terminates or when there is some sort of exception. 
join method on the Thread is there to essentially wait until thread/s terminate. You can also provide timeout (wait for only certain time)

**1. In the above code, why are the threads only executing one cycle of the while loop when join() is never being called? I would expect the threads to be never ending.**

How do you know its executing one cycle ? With your code, my tasks are running forever
My output,

```
Starting Thread-2
Thread-1: Wed Mar 13 12:03:42 2019
Exiting Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Thread-1: Wed Mar 13 12:03:43 2019
Exiting Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Thread-2: Wed Mar 13 12:03:44 2019
Exiting Thread-2
Starting Thread-2
Thread-1: Wed Mar 13 12:03:44 2019
Exiting Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Thread-1: Wed Mar 13 12:03:46 2019
Exiting Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
#and goes on
```

**How would I make a threading program run until the user decides to exit it? My main goal is to have a script scan and analyze files until the user tells it to quit.**

Depends on how you write your target/ runnable method. You can have logics there to run forever. Think of thread as a piece of work that is being spun off off current (main) program. You should design your tasks to be atomic and simple !

Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html)